# .htaccess redirect all .shtml files in a directory tree leaving others alone

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm terrible at redirects/rewrites.  I've got many .shtml files in a particular subdirectory tree of the site that I want to 301 to .html.  All other .shtml files should be left alone.  Using Apache, the RewriteEngine is on.

Specifically, change `www.domain.com/homes/cityname/file.shtml` to .html
for many cities and files. The `homes` subdirectory is constant.

`www.domain.com/status.shtml` to remain untouched, among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/homes/(.*)\.shtml /homes/$1.html
```

Of if you'd rather use mod_rewrite over mod_alias:

```
RewriteRule ^homes/(.*)\.shtml /homes/$1.html [R=301]
```